# redirect one domain to another using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain **"xyz.com.au"** which is **hosted** on godaddy.

I have another **"xyz.com"** which is **not hosted.**

**I want** that when user enter **"xyz.com"** in browser, they will automatically **get re-directed to "xyz.com.au"(Without purchasing any new hosting plan for "xyz.com" )**

How can i do that? What should i write in "htaccess" file of "xyz.com.au".

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to do. If the domain xyz.com does not exist then someone would see a DNS error in their Browser. Or if someone does own the xyz.com domain then they would be sent to that domain.